# Не получается передать interface listener в Фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-interface

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GridViewClickListenerSetter.PermissionCheckOnClicked{
private static final String LOG = "myLog";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    MainFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MainFragmentPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    verifyStoragePermissions();
}

// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

private void verifyStoragePermissions() {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}

@Override
public void itemViewClicked() {
    verifyStoragePermissions();
}
```

}

**FragmentBeginner.java**

```
public class FragmentBeginner extends Fragment {

private BooksAdapter booksAdapter;
private boolean isCISlanguage = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    if(lang.equals("ru") || lang.equals("kk") || lang.equals("kz") || lang.equals("uk")){
        booksAdapter = new BooksAdapter(getActivity(), BooksUrls.getBeginnerRu());
        isCISlanguage = true;
    }else{
        booksAdapter = new BooksAdapter(getActivity(), BooksUrls.getBeginnerEng());
        isCISlanguage = false;
    }
}

public FragmentBeginner() {
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beginner, container, false);
    GridView gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.beginnerGridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(booksAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    return view;
}

GridViewClickListenerSetter itemClickListener = new GridViewClickListenerSetter(getActivity(), isCISlanguage, ((MainActivity)getActivity()));
```

}

**GridViewClickListenerSetter.java**

```
public class GridViewClickListenerSetter implements GridView.OnItemClickListener{

private final Context context;
private boolean isCISlanguage = false;
private PermissionCheckOnClicked listener;

public GridViewClickListenerSetter(Context context, boolean isCISlanguage, PermissionCheckOnClicked listener){
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.isCISlanguage = isCISlanguage;
}

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        listener.itemViewClicked();
        Book book;
        if(isCISlanguage){
            book = BooksUrls.getBeginnerRu(position);
        }else{
            book = BooksUrls.getBeginnerEng(position);
        }
        context.startService(BookDownloadService.getDownloadService(
            context,
            book.getUrl(),
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"));
    }

public interface PermissionCheckOnClicked{
    void itemViewClicked();
}
```

}

**MainActivity** имплементит интерфейс **PermissionCheckOnClicked**  класса **GridViewClickListenerSetter**.
Во Фрагменте **FragmentBeginner.java** я в конструктор передаю активити с помощью `getActivity();`
Но вылетает ошибка в строчке `listener.itemViewClicked();` в классе **GridViewClickListenerSetter.java**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.studio.houmi.firebasesample.GridViewClickListenerSetter$PermissionCheckOnClicked.itemViewClicked()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.studio.houmi.firebasesample.GridViewClickListenerSetter.onItemClick(GridViewClickListenerSetter.java:27)
                                                                                 at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:346)
                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1576)
                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3962)
                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView$7.run(AbsListView.java:6042)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7329)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот в этой строчка

```
GridViewClickListenerSetter itemClickListener = new GridViewClickListenerSetter(getActivity(), isCISlanguage, ((MainActivity)getActivity()));
```

Выполняется в тот момент, когда вы создаете объект. Видимо где в адаптере пишете что-то  вроде

```
Fragment newFragment = new FragmentBeginner();
fragmentManaget.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, newFragment).commit();
```

В первой строчке вы создаете объект, и создаются все его поля, в том числе itemClickListener. А прикрепляете фрагмент к активити только во второй строчке. Соответственно, при создании itemClickListener вы вызываете getActivity() и получаете null, т.к. фрагмент еще ни к чему не прикреплен.

Создавайте itemClickListener  в любом методе из класса Fragment: onAttach, onCreate, onCreateView или onViewCreated. Они вызываются только когда фрагмент прикреплен к активити.

Comment: Ваше последнее предложение, нужно сделать так: т.е, вместо моего конструктора сделать GridViewClickListenerSetter(getActivity(), boolean bool).

Comment: Посмотрел внимательнее, и понял, что третий параметр не активити принимает, а интерфейс. Мой косяк, в это плане особо менять ничего не стоит

Comment: кстати а почему так ? Активити же имплемнтит интерфейс

Comment: Context и activity это разные вещи ?

Comment: Activity наследуется от Context. То есть в если нужно указать контекст, можно уверенно указывать активити. Примерно по тому же принципу работает третий ваш параметр. Он должен принять реализованный интерфейс, а вы передаете куда больший объект, но содержащий все, что онт него требует указанный тип параметра. Потому код работает. Но вот не каждая реализация вашего интерфейса будет активити, потому из интерфейса контекст вы уже не получите. Вот и приходится два раза передавать активити, один  раз как контекст, один как интерфейс